# Groovy compiler calling wrong overloaded java method

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I searched StackOverflow before posting this question but I wasn't able to find the right answer. Sorry if this is a repost. My problem is this:

I have a method that is overloaded in my java class:

```
class ABC{

    public boolean doSomething(String path, ArrayList<SomeObject> objList){
        // calling the method below in a loop
    }

    public boolean doSomething(String path, SomeObject obj){
       // Some code here
    }
}
```

I'm calling the above class from my groovy code like this:

```
void performDoSomething(ABC abc, String path, String[] strList){
    def list = []
    for (str in strList) {
        SomeObject sObj = new SomeObject(str)    // EDIT: sorry I missed this line before
        list.add(sObj)
    }
    if (abc) abc.doSomething(path, list)
}
```

The problem is that the groovy compiler is calling the abc.doSomething(String str, SomeObject obj) method instead of abc.doSomething(String str, ArrayList objList) method.

I'm using eclipse IDE with grails plugin (STS) and this is part of a bigger grails project (our company has a lot of legacy code in java).

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I have tried 
    abc.doSomething(path, list as ArrayList)
too but I'm getting the same result..

Comment: Is Groovy really supposed to turn a `String[]` into an `ArrayList<Object>`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo by me, I have changed it now

Comment: Is Groovy supposed to turn a [] into an ArrayList<Object>?

Comment: As you can see I'm using the string to create "SomeObject sObj = new SomeObject(str)" and adding sObj into the list.

Comment: does any call to doSomething with arraylist succeed, at all?

Comment: Yes, it works in java but if I use the object "ABC" in groovy it doesn't get the right method

Comment: I didn't ask about SomeObject, I asked about [] and ArrayList<Object>. If Groovy does anything I would expect it to map [] to List<Object>, not ArrayList<Object>. But I'm clearly no Groovy expert.

Comment: Your code works for me - the correct method get called, with no changes required. Now, I'm not using Eclipse, I just wrote up the two java classes in vim, and compiled at the command-line, then ran the groovy part as a script from the command-line - but it all seems to work fine. Oh, and btw, groovy _does_ create an ArrayList for [] by default (it needs to be a concrete class to be instantiated, so List won't do...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was with the eclipse's grails/groovy plugin and not with the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you reproduce this with a simple example using the classes you mention? I tried, but I got the expected behavior.

**SomeObject.java:**:

```
public class SomeObject {
    public String what;
    public SomeObject(String what) {
        this.what = what;
    }
}
```

**ABC.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class ABC {
    public void doSomething(String path, List<SomeObject> objects) {
        System.out.println("Doing something with many objects");
        for (SomeObject obj : objects) {
            doSomething(path, obj);
        }
    }

    public void doSomething(String path, SomeObject obj) {
        System.out.println("Doing something with: " + obj.what);
    }
}
```

**test.groovy:**

```
void performDoSomething(ABC abc, String path, String[] strList){
    def list = []
    for (str in strList) {
        SomeObject sObj = new SomeObject(str)    // EDIT: sorry I missed this line before
        list.add(sObj)
    }
    if (abc) abc.doSomething(path, list)
}

performDoSomething(new ABC(), 'some path', ['hello', 'world'] as String[])
```

I run this doing (in the same directory as the files):

```
javac *.java
groovy test.groovy
```

And the output I get is:

```
Doing something with many objects
Doing something with: hello
Doing something with: world
```

Which means that the correct overloaded method, `doSomething(String, List<SomeObject>)`, is being called by Groovy. This is what is expected, as Groovy uses the runtime type information on the methods to decide which overloaded version to call (an example of this can be found [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Visitor+Pattern)). I would *not* recommend changing the signature of `doSomthing` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797113/581845), as it will pollute the class' interface unnecessarily; the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem was with eclipse grails/groovy plugin and not with my code :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to make sure your overloading isn't at all ambiguous.

Make the two calls have dramatically different APIs and see if the problem goes away or if the new error messages point you at a groovy issue.

```
public class ABC {
  public boolean doSomething(String path, int ignored, ArrayList<Object> objList){
    // calling the method below in a loop
  }

  public boolean doSomething(String path, Object obj){
   // Some code here
  }
}
```

Comment: I could do that but the java class "ABC" is used by a LOT of other java classes all over our (old) codebase. We are upgrading our framework to grails and there are many more overloaded methods that have to be changed if I take this approach.

Comment: Also, I just tried your approach and it seems to be calling the correct method. But I don't think we can afford to use this solution throughout our code base :/

Comment: I am sorry I was unclear. I was hoping that disambiguating the calls would highlight the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out the answer. It's an eclipse IDE problem, I had to run the "grails clean" command and the project was rebuilt. Now the groovy code is calling the correct java method.